# Unable to locate factory for [Laravel\Passport\Client]

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-passport, phpunit

I have a laravel app with passport installed to manage api auth. I'm trying to write some tests but I'm unable to create a Client as per the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/passport#testing) on laravel. I've googled similar SO answers but they all suggest using setUp and tearDown methods which I am doing. When I run the test I get

```
InvalidArgumentException 

Unable to locate factory for [Laravel\Passport\Client].
```

How can I get this to work?

Below is my code. I have included the Client model from the passport package and I am using the setUp and tearDown methods as suggested in similar SO answers.

I've tried `composer dump-autoload` and `php artisan config:cache`.

```
use Laravel\Passport\Passport;
use Laravel\Passport\Client;

... 

use RefreshDatabase;

protected function setUp(): void
{
    parent::setUp();
}

protected function tearDown(): void
{
    parent::tearDown();
}

public function testAPIEndpointFailsWhenNoParamIsSet()
{
    Passport::actingAsClient(
        factory(Client::class)->create(),
        ['*']
    );

    $response = $this->postJson('/api/endpoint', [
        'param' => ''
    ]);

    $response->assertStatus(401)
        ->assertJson(['message' => 'Unauthenticated.']);
}
```

Comment: maybe `composer dumpautoload` could help, and then do `artisan serve` after that.

Comment: tried composer dump-autoload

Comment: clearing all cache and restart the laravel works for me last 2 days. `artisan config:clear` and `artisan cache:clear`

Comment: Tried that already too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

passport client factory should be existed on publishing ...

if it did not .... make it your self:

from : [here](https://github.com/laravel/passport/pull/1171/commits/53b8bbfd7aaef688afca617137bc9a2fa7528569#diff-d627f83bb7e3bbe6ec84a20b14e0a1d1R8)

```
use Laravel\Passport\Passport;
use Laravel\Passport\Client;

$factory->define(Client::class, function (Faker $faker) {
    return [
        'user_id' => null,
        'name' => $faker->company,
        'secret' => Str::random(40),
        'redirect' => $faker->url,
        'personal_access_client' => 0,
        'password_client' => 0,
        'revoked' => 0,
    ];
});
```

Comment: I'm using the client middleware for this endpoint though not web or api.

Comment: I copied the factory file from laravel passport into my own factory directory and it works now.